# Marginalising over Dependent Random Variables

Tags: bayesian, posterior, marginal-distribution

Suppose I have two RVs, $A$, and $B$.

Every place I have looked thus far suggests the following for marginalisation, which for me is fine:

$f_A(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{A,B}(a,b)db $.

However, **has it been implicitly assumed** anywhere that $A$ and $B$ are independent random variables?

What is confusing is the following scenario:

Consider RVs where $B = A^2$. Is the following true, (with perhaps abuse of notation, I'm not sure how to write this out correctly):

$f_A(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{A,B}(a,b)db
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{A,A^2}(a,a^2)da^2  $.

It just **feels strange** for me, that you can integrate some "a" and still have a function of "a".

Is it possible to have clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for your first question is no, $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{B}$ don't have to be independent [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution#Two-variable_case). About your second question, note that your integration region is no longer from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, but from zero to $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks :). But regardless of the new limits, the overlap of the variables still trips me out (a and a^2 both in the integral yet some f(a) still remains after integrating). Maybe my mind is too stuck in a high school view of integration? I just cant convince myself why it is ok for some f(a) to remain since it feels like the integral did consider "a" implicitly through "$a^2$".

Comment: I think what's bothering you is to substitute $ b $ for $ a^2 $. Because if $\textbf{B}=\textbf{A}^2$, you have to make a change of variable, and the integral will not be $da^2 $, so the last equality is incorrect at this point.

Comment: Thanks. I independently came to a somewhat similar conclusion just recently, so it is nice to know that we both agree. I will mark you as the final answer to this Q and maybe from here look to manually integrate out some dependent RV  to enforce some of the principles into my mind